# How can I get a native driver database context with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I'm using Mongoose, and I'd like to use the native driver for some things. One of the things I'd like to do is make a query for a GridFS file. You normally do that as such:

db.fs.files.findOne({});

However, mongoose.connection.db doesn't have fs defined. So I need a native driver db object, not the Mongoose one. Is there a way that I can get such an object from Mongoose?